# insert multiple data with query mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to upload marks of students.. so if I use a loop to insert multiple student's marks.

Is it make the load on the server?? because query executes multiple times.
Is there any other way to insert multiple data without loop.

```
<?php 
$roll_no=$_POST['roll_no'];
$department=$_POST['department'];
$semester=$_POST['semester'];
if($course && $department && $semester)
{
    foreach($roll_no as $c)
    {
        $q="INSERT INTO allocoursestudent(roll_no,department,semester) VALUES('$c','".$department[$c]."','"$semester[$c]"')";
        if(mysqli_query($con,$q))
           {
             $response=  "Data inserted";
           }
    }
    echo($response);
}else
{
    echo("Enter Data first");
}
```

Comment: I would advice to include some code into your question. In this way, you will increase the chances to get an answer and reduce the chances to get your question flagged and removed.

Comment: i added the code ... please check.. i think when i add 200 students at once ..by using loop it make load on server.Is their alternative way?

Answer (score 2):

Well here is the solution

```
    <?php 
    $roll_no=$_POST['roll_no'];
    $lenght=count($roll_no);
    $department=$_POST['department'];
    $semester=$_POST['semester'];
    if($course!="" && $department!="" && $semester!="")
    {
        for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)
        {
$q="INSERT INTO allocoursestudent(roll_no,department,semester) values($roll_no[$i],$department[$i],$semester[$i])";

            if(mysqli_query($con,$q))
               {
                 $response=  "Data inserted";
               }else
               {
               $response=  "Error";
               }
        }
        echo($response);
    }else
    {
        echo("Enter Data first");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can insert multiple rows in a single SQL statement, like so:

```
insert into tbl (col1, col2)
values (row1_val1, row1_val2), (row2_val1, row2_val2) [...]
```

The values for each row are parenthesized and separated by a comma.

Using a higher level database API like propel, Laravel Eloquent, doctrine, makes this type of operation simple to do.

Answer (score 1):

for example this code block you can replace with your own code.

```
 INSERT INTO table (a,b) VALUES (1,2), (2,3), (3,4);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

### LARAVEL USAGE

```
        $codes = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $codes[$i]['code'] = $this->genUuid();
            $codes[$i]['secret'] = uniqid();
            $codes[$i]['day'] = request('day');
            $codes[$i]['label'] = request('label');
            $codes[$i]['state'] = 1;
            $codes[$i]['created_at'] = Carbon::now();
            $codes[$i]['updated_at'] = Carbon::now();
        }

        Code::insert($codes);
```